# Sorting an array incorrectly

Tags: c#

I have class A. In this class I've written a `CompareTo` method, like that:

```
int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
{ 
    if (obj == null)
        return -1;
    Invioce inv = obj as Invioce;
    if (inv == null)
        return -1;
    if ((GetInvoiceAmount() < inv.GetInvoiceAmount()))
        return -1;
    return Convert.ToInt32(GetInvoiceAmount() > inv.GetInvoiceAmount());
}
```

Then I created an array of 10 `A`s (`A[] a = new A[10]`) ,and I set `a[0]` as a random `A`.
The result of `Array.sort(a)` was: `a[0..8]` are `null` and `a[9]` is the random `A`. What can I do that the array will be sorted correctly? (`a[0]` has to be the random `A`). Thanks everybody.

Comment: Are you aware, that your code can be replaced by `new A[10].OrderBy(inv => inv.GetInvoiceAmount())`? This will just work.

Comment: I also find converting a `bool` using `Convert.ToInt32` to be an obfuscation of the meaning of that line. Hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

First you can remove the first comparison (unless you really need to have an optimized comparison).  `as Invoice` will result in `inv` being null if `obj` is not of type `Invoice`.  Consider any possible loss of performance a gain in code maintainability.

Secondly you can take advantage that the result doesn't have to be -1, 0, 1 but Less Than zero, zero, and greater than zero to represent precedence.  In this case subtracting the instance from the compared instance will produce a valid result.

The following function will result in the instance preceding any non-invoice or null object, otherwise it will precede an invoice with a greater invoice amount.

```
int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
{ 
    Invioce inv = obj as Invioce;
    return (inv == null) ? -1 : GetInvoiceAmount() - inv.GetInvoiceAmount();
}
```